# How to view the exact size of a file in Google Drive (e.g., expressed in bytes)?

Tags: google-drive

How to view the exact size of a file in Google Drive (e.g., expressed in bytes)?

E.g., in the following I would like to know the exact file size, not rounded n KB:

[image]

[image]

Link to the folder if you want to try: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4y6Mj_UZoTEWW9IRWhJV2xnbVk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there are two different "detail views" in Google Drive. The one I showed in the question doesn't have the exact size, whereas the second one has it…:

[image]

[image]